# Consulta con groupby a una determinada columna de un dataTable

Tags: c#, select, group-by

Buenas tengo un `DataTable` con 3 campos (*id_vehiculo,vehiculo,id_marca*) con unos datos que recojo de una consulta a un SQLServer, y querría llenar un `combobox` un `group_by` de todos los *id_marca* del dataTable.
Pero no sé ni por donde empezar, en mi cabeza parecía fácil, haciendo algo del estilo:

```
string[]marcas= dt.Rows["marca"].Select(x=> x.Value)
```

Pero está claro que no lo sé enfocar porque no puedo hacer eso, y buscando información de como hacer el `GroupBy` ya me he acabado de liar.
¿Me podéis echar un cable por favor?

Comment: Pues, creo que podrías empezar por la documentación de `Linq` https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/ :D

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he logrado de la siguiente manera, por si a alguien le sirve o alguien opina que hay alguna forma mejor de hacerlo.

```
IEnumerable<string> d = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x.Field<string>("marca")).Distinct();
```